# How to update specific download path in chrome in karate framework

Tags: selenium, karate, karate-call-single

While executing our automation script in remote few file validation scenarios are breaking due download location keep changing. So I would like create a folder in C and set default download path for chrome like in selenium. How to implement the same in karate if someone help me that will. I have used userDataDir but not didn't work

By default download directory in every machine is C\User\username\download but I would like to update C\Folder for chrome